# Windows11: How do I find out exactly where SAML-WebLogIn on Windows fails after redirect back to Windows?

Tags: entra-id, saml, keycloak, windows-11, federated

I managed to enable federated Logins for our Microsoft tenant so that if you login to, say, office.com and enter your username (e.g. "foo@baz.com") you're then redirected to our Keycloak instance, you authenticate there, you're then redirected back to office.com and successfully logged in.

I now want to enable the same functionality for our Windows Education machines. By using the Windows Configuration Designer, I enabled the SharedPC setting,also enabled FederatedAuthentication/EnableWegSignInForPrimaryUser and Policies/Authentication/EnableWebSignIn and set /ConfigureWebSignInAllowedUrls to the Keycloak domain.
The device itself is managed through Entra.

This seems to work at first - if a "primary user" (i.e. one existing in Entra) tries to login, he get the usual flow.
If someone from the federated domain tries to login, it also *seems* to work at first - you get the redirect to Keycloak, you enter your credentials successfully and then you're redirected back.

At which point you only see: "Something went wrong". That's it. That's the whole error message. Trying to sift through the event logs didn't yield anything either (or I didn't look in the right spot) and Keycloak only says: "Hey, it 100% worked on **my** end!" so I'm not sure where to go from here.
The juxtaposition between it working for the website and not working on Windows makes it more complicated as well. And MS support just tells me: "Yeah, 3rd party, go away." Plus, they actively deleted their SAML test tool which was supposed to help you diagnose just such a problem.

Anyone else have an idea what I can do to diagnose this?